# finding element in very big list in less than O(n)

Tags: haskell

I want to check if an element exists in a list (a very big one in 10,000,000 order) in a O(1) instead of O(n). Lists with `elem x ys` take O(n)
So i want to use another data type/constructor but it has to be in `Prelude`(not Array); any suggestions? And if i have to build me data type what it would be like?

Also to sort a big list of numbers in the same order (10,000,000)and indexing an element in the shortest time possible.

Comment: If you restrict yourself to `Prelude`, you have to build a suitable datatype yourself. If you use e.g. `Data.Set`, you get O(log n) lookup. What is it you actually want to do? The best data structure to use depends on that.

Comment: I want to get the union-intersection of very 2 big lists; i did implement my own union-intersection using recursion-foldr-foldl` but every time i need to check if( elem x ys )that take O(n) check for each element, so at the end i have O(n+m)

Comment: and i want to sort the data after the operation too, so i need a datatype that would allow fast operations; any idea?

Comment: What's a union-intersection? The pair of union and intersection? What is known about these lists (apart from their approximate length)?

Comment: union of two list: union [5,4] [6,4] = [4,5,6] 
intersection  [5,4] [6,4] = [4]
they're two separate functions; i just wrote them that way as they have a similar implementation. They are already implemented for Lists, but i wanted my own to use for any  dataType

What i know about the lists: they don't have to be lists; they are just set of numbers, and i want to have the union of those 2 sets for example and they are huge sets.
Some answer there suggested BST; I thought that there would be a solution other than the well known data structures, but i may implement it if there's not.

Comment: I know what union and intersection are, but I've never come across them hyphenated together. So you want the union and the intersection. I'd say the easiest way to get decent complexity is using `Data.Set` or `Data.IntSet` (if the type is `Int`). If that's not fast enough, you could try building `Data.Vector[.Unboxed].Vector`s from them, sort those and build union resp. intersection by a parallel traversal.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use anything but `Data.List` and `Prelude`, so i guess i have to build my own dataType after all. I may try building the standard ones on my own like BST. Thanks a lot for your efforts

Comment: What the four-letter-word. Still, sorting and parallel traversal seems the way to go, sorting lists isn't **that** much slower than sorting `Vector`s. A BST only gives good performance if it's sufficiently balanced, and that would probably be more work than adequate for a homework.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to search for an item in a data set in O(1) time is if you already know where it is, but then you don't need to search for it. For unsorted data, search is O(n) time. For sorted data, search is O(log n) time.

Answer (score 4):

You should use either [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) or [Hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable). Neither of them is in Prelude; moreover, both rely on Array to be available.

The only left option is some kind of tree; I would suggest [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29). It’s not hard to implement and it also gives you sorting for free.

UPDATE: oops! I have forgotten that heap doesn’t provide lookup. [BST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) is your choice, then.

Comment: hash table is also O(n) worst-case